# Incorrect syntax near the keyword CASE when trying to use in storedprocedure

Tags: sql

Check the SQL Query below in `storedprocedure`. I am trying to implement `CASE` to set some values to the `@Query` variable, but the `CASE` syntax is throwing error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.

```
DECLARE @Query AS VARCHAR(max);

CASE
    WHEN @Type=1 THEN 
    SET @Query = ''
    WHEN @Type=2 THEN
    SET @Query = ''
    WHEN @Type=3 THEN 
    SET @Query = ''
    ELSE
    SET @Query = '';
    
END;
```

[image: Picture]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: You need to use select before your case;

Answer (score 2):

You want a `CASE` **expression** used in a single `SET`:

```
SET @query = (CASE WHEN @Type = 1 THEN ''
                   WHEN @Type = 2 THEN ''
                   WHEN @Type = 3 THEN ''
                   ELSE ''
              END);
```

Of course, everything in your `CASE` is setting the value to `''`, so conditional logic is not needed.  I assume your actual code has different values.

Answer (score 0):

You should start with `SELECT`, otherwise it's not a valid `CASE` statement. Also maybe you need to store the Result of the CASE in a separate Variable like `SELECT @Query = CASE WHEN ...`

Comment: In a SELECT you can only have a case _expression_. However, a case _statement_ is used in stored procedures for conditional execution of code. (If supported by the dbms.)